# XACML Obligations

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3

How do we use obligations in XACML? Any reference will be helpful
The scenario is that the obligations should refer the PIP and retrun the result to PEP

Thanks

#### Example from the author's comment:

```xml
<ObligationExpressions>
    <ObligationExpression ObligationId="EmailObligation" FulfillOn="Permit">
        <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
            <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
    </ObligationExpression> 
</ObligationExpressions>
```

Comment: Like this                  <ObligationExpressions>
 <ObligationExpression ObligationId="EmailObligation" FulfillOn="Permit">
  <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
   <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
 </ObligationExpression>
</ObligationExpressions>

Comment: I moved your example to the question. If my answer is satisfactory, do accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obligations in XACML (as well as Advice introduced in XACML 3.0) are used to enrich the authorization flow.

A typical XACML response only bears a decision (either of Permit, Deny, Not Applicable, or Indeterminate). But, what if you want to tell the user why access is denied? What if you want to implement a "Break the glass" scenario?

This is where obligations and advice come in handy. Here are a few examples:

- deny Alice access to document D + obligation: email her manager, Bob, to let him know Alice tried to access document D.
- deny Doctor House the right to view medical record + obligation: tell Doctor House he can "break the glass" to access the medical record.
- Allow Joe to view Document D but first watermark the document before returning it to Joe

In XACML 3.0 obligations and advice can have variable parts such as - in the examples above - the manager's email. Those parts can be retrieved from a PIP.

Comment: Is there anyway in XACML to define Pre-obligations and Post-Obligations concept?
Foe Example: To Approve a Proposal Department Chair need to Sign it <Pre-obligation> and then Post obligation is to notify the Dean For Approval next workflow.

Comment: They are both handled as obligations. You would actually send 2 XACML requests in that case though

Comment: I did this by specifying two different obligationType i.e. preobligation and postobligation in two of the AttributeExpression's attributeId inside ObligationExpression and in client I first check that all preobligation are fulfilled executing and validating postobligation.